# Keytool command not found

Tags: java, keytool

I have sonar-scanner on my container. It has embedded jre. I am not able to run keytool from my jre/bin nor I can find keytool in my container. Can you please let me know how to install keytool

Comment: They're probably using a reduced JRE, to keep sonar-scanner distribution size down.

Answer (score 0):

You can install jdk firstly. Then if you can install it with default options, You would find keytool at c:\Program Files\java\jdkxxx\bin.

Comment: Thanks. I am still not sure if I have to install the whole JDK inorder to get keytool running

Comment: You can try to copy keytool to embedded jre/bin after installation and then remove installed jdk. I haven't tried it, but may be that is working. Of course, it is important that both jdk and jre is the same version in that method. I hope that solve your problem.

Comment: I tried copying keytool from another virtual machine into the container but nothing worked. I still get error while executing sonar-scanner from docker container as "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"